# Write log from applet, while debugging in eclipse

Tags: java, file-io, applet, japplet

I am trying to write a log file from an applet.

When running as a Java application, I am able to write to the files, 
but when running as an applet, I get `.\logs\test.log (The system cannot find the path specified)`.

How do I permit it to write to disk, **while debugging** using eclipse?

**EDIT: is it because of the backslashes?**

Comment: it is most likely because applets run in a restricted environment in the browser, and may not have access to local file system ('local' being the computer where the browser is running)

Comment: Still, shouldn't that be possible in the debug environment of eclipse?

Comment: Its a debug version, I'm using appletviewer to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write whatever you want from applet in temp file, to create temp file [Try this](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/CreateTempFile.html)
. Also you get system temp folder in java and create your file there, [Read this.](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/Getoperatingsystemtemporarydirectoryfolder.htm) @Yoni is right you have limited permissions when you are in applet.